# WSGI Application - sqlalchemy can't create_engine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wsgi, werkzeug

I'm trying to build a small WSGI application with Werkzeug. I have followed this [tutorial](http://mitsuhiko.pocoo.org/werkzeug-docs/tutorial.html) it's so simple and clear. However I encounter this error:

```
File "/Users/username/my_app/assigment2/app.py", line 38, in __init__
self.database_engine = create_engine(db_uri)
File "/Users/Data/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 386, in create_engine
return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/../lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 51, in create
dialect_cls = u.get_dialect()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_dialect'
```

I have imported all SqlAlchemy modules

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session, scoped_session
```

The application fails at the **init** of the app.

```
class App(object):
def __init__(self):
    local.app = self
    self.database_engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI )
    self.jinja_env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('app', '/templates'))
    self.dispatch = SharedDataMiddleware(self.dispatch, {'/static':  STATIC_PATH})

def init_database(self):
    metadata.create_all(self.database_engine)

def dispatch(self, environ, start_response):
    local.app = self
    request = Response(environ)
    local.url_= adapter = url_map.bind_to_environ(environ)
    #adapter = url_map.bind_to_environ(environ)
    try:
        endpoint, value = adapter.match()
        handler = getattr(views, endpoint)
        response = handler(request, **values)
    except HTTPException as e:
        response = e
    return ClosingIterator(response(environ, strat_response),
                            [session.remove, local_manager.cleanup])

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
```

the databse_uri looks like this

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/name_db'

STATIC_PATH = path.join(path.dirname('/static'), 'static')
```

Why I can't create my app like this:

```
def make_app():
   my_app = app.App()
   return my_app
```

I am running on Gunicorn

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:9000 app:make_app
```

New error:

```
TypeError: make_app() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:9000 app:App
```

What happens when there is a request:

```
app.App(environ, start_response)
```

But what you really want is:

```
your_app = app.App(path, db_uri)
your_app(environ, start_response)
```

Change gunicorn invocation to something like this:

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:9000 'app:App("/static/path", "postgresql://...")'
```

Comment: Why I can't do this than.

Comment: @Rich Update the gunicorn call to `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:9000 'app:make_app()'`

Comment: I'm sorry, this `'app:make_app()'` is supported by uwsgi, not by gunicorn. You have to create instance of your `App` in the script as a variable and just call `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:9000 app:my_app`